# gram-schmidt with polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra

With the inner product $<f,g>=\int_{-1}^{1} f(x)g(x) dx$, apply the gram-schmidt algorithm to construct orthogonal polynomials from basis elements {1,x,x^2}.

I am thinking that the answer would simply be:

$p_0(x)=1$

$p_1(x)=x-\frac{<x,p_0>}{<p_0,p_0>}p_0(x)$

$p_0(x)=x^2-\frac{<x^2,p_0>}{<p_0,p_0>}p_0(x)-\frac{<x^2,p_1>}{<p_1,p_1>}p_1(x)$

is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks correct to me, with one caveat: $\langle 1, 1\rangle = 2$, so some rescaling is necessary if you want your answers to be orthonormal.

Comment: but since I just need orthogonal this works right?

Comment: yeah, in that case you'll be fine

Comment: Also, am I able to replace the $p_0$ with 1 to simplify my final answer?

Comment: so like: $p_1(x)=x-\frac{<x,p_0>}{<p_0,p_0>}p_0(x)=x-\frac{<x,1>}{<1,1>}$?

Comment: I would also expect that you should also compute $\langle x, 1\rangle$ and so forth.

Comment: to compute that I just take the integral right? so <1,1>= x from -1 to 1 , so 1+1=2

Comment: Correct, each inner product is evaluated by computing the corresponding definite integral.